# how to mock `await asyncio.Future()`?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I want to write a asyncio main function in pytest:

```
async def main(host, port):
    log.debug('starting websockets server...')
    async with websockets.serve(myserver, host, port): 
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

async def test_main():
    with patch('websockets.legacy.server.Serve') as mock_serve:
        mock_serve.return_value=''
        with patch('_asyncio.Future') as mock_future:
            mock_future.return_value = ''
            await main('','')  # <- hang in this
```

but it always stop in `await asyncio.Future()` , any idea? thanks!

Comment: I think this is a good use-case for valuing unit tests in combination with integration tests. For the majority of the logic of testing the websocket, you do not absolutely need to run it through you main method... instead you could handle doing setup where you replace components with mocks passed to constructors. For testing if the main is working correctly, you can create a real instance of the websocket server and validating simple end-to-end tests that validate the framework setup, but not necessarily the business logic.

Comment: `asyncio.Future()` is a primitive, not something to be mocked. It's like asking how to mock functions or integers. Not a specific function or value, but all integers in general. What you're really asking is how to complete the wait operation, not mock the default value of the Future type

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to *not* construct the `Future` instance inside `main`. Pass it from the outside, eg as a parameter whose default is `asyncio.Future()` allowing you to pass a different one that can be completed by the unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it that you dont patch the `Future`. Try debugging it with a breakpoint on `await asyncio.Future()` and you will see that `type(asyncio.Future)` is not a mock. But if you patch using `with patch('asyncio.Future') as mock_future:` and try the same thing, you will get `type(asyncio.Future)` is `unittest.mock.MagicMock`.